# jquery - test if a specific checkbox in range is checked within a fieldset

Tags: jquery

I need to see if any checkboxes within a range in a fieldset are checked

```
<fieldset id="issues">
    <input name="A" id="issue_0" type="checkbox" value="A" /> <--- this one
    <input name="B" id="issue_1" type="checkbox" value="B" />
    <input name="C" id="issue_2" type="checkbox" value="C" />
    <input name="D" id="issue_3" type="checkbox" value="D" />
    <input name="E" id="issue_4" type="checkbox" value="E" />
</fieldset>
```

The field set is #issues, this works fine to see if any of them are checked

```
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ){
  console.log("One of them is checked");
}
```

But I want to see if a specific checkbox by index is checked, ie if the first one is checked. I tried this...

```
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"][0]').is(':checked') ){
  console.log("Item one is checked");
}
```

but it doesn't work

How do I target a specific checkbox by index within a fieldset?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]').first().is(':checked') ){
    console.log("Item one is checked");
}
```

Use `.first()` to grab the first one in the wrapped set.

Also I'd recommend using `.prop()` as it is easier to deal with when it comes to cross-browser issues!

```
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]').first().prop('checked') === true ){
    console.log("Item one is checked");
}​
```

If you needed to get a specific index you could do:

```
var index = 2;
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]').eq(index).prop('checked') === true ){
    console.log("Item one is checked");
}​
```

Comment: Woooot! Thank you. As a matter of interest how would I detect the second one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `eq()` method:

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

```
 if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).is(':checked') ){
    console.log("Item one is checked");
 }
```

or use the `:eq()` selector:

```
$('#issues input[type="checkbox"]:eq(0)') // selects the first input
$('#issues input[type="checkbox"]:eq(1)') // selects the second input
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to select the nth child:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
if( $('#issues input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(1)').is(':checked') ){
    console.log("child one is checked");
 }
```

Comment: +1. I was interested in comparing execution time between `nth-child` and `eq` and as more inputs you add as faster `nth-child` gets: http://jsperf.com/nth-vs-eq